# How to retrieve a query result in a computed field?

Tags: database, entities

I'm trying to run the following select in a computed field, but it doesn't work: any clue on what is going wrong ?

```
$nid = $node->nid;

$result = db_query('SELECT description FROM {taxonomy_term_data} AS ttd 
                    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} AS ti ON ti.tid = ttd.tid 
                    WHERE ttd.vid = :vid AND ti.nid = :nid', 
                  array(':vid' => 16, ':nid' => $nid));

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7) doesn't return a column, to do this you need to fetch it using [`fetchField()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_result/6#comment-1013):

```
$nid = $node->nid;

$result = db_query('SELECT description FROM {taxonomy_term_data} AS ttd 
                    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} AS ti ON ti.tid = ttd.tid 
                    WHERE ttd.vid = :vid AND ti.nid = :nid', 
                  array(':vid' => 16, ':nid' => $nid));

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $result->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one row (the first one returned) that you are concerned with, you can wrap your db_query() in db_fetch_array() (or db_fetch_object() if you prefer objects) to access the contents of the row it returns, eg,

```
$row = db_fetch_array(db_query( /* whatever */ ));
```

and now $row is an associative array representing the contents of the row based upon your query.

Check out http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_fetch_array/6 for more info.

Comment: Regarding how the OP put its parameters in the question `:nid`, I'm pretty sure he's using D7 ;)

Comment: Jimajamma says "D'oh!"

Comment: Yep, tostinni is right: I'm using D7. Anyway, thanks for your reply :)